# Form autofill with LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, hubspot

EDIT: LINKEDIN SUPPORT - do you check Stack Overflow for posts tagged with linkedin like it says on your website?

Have been directed here by LinkedIn developer site.

I have found the following article ( https://community.unbounce.com/unbounce/topics/guide-implementing-linkedins-new-autofill-feature ), plus a couple of others that talk about LinkedIn autofill, but there seems to be no documentation on the LinkedIn developers site. Is this still in beta? Is there a date set for its official release and for documentation release?

I wish to implement this on our company HubSpot landing pages, but so far haver been unsuccessful ('Your request could not be completed') and I am wondering if this is because it has not been made available to the public yet?

I have seen it used on 2 sites, but I assume these are using formstack or another application that has been granted access to the functionality?

Would very much appreciate some info on this great potential new feature.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this thread while I was researching Autofill. Looks like you have to use LinkedIn Lead Accelerator for you to be able to use it. And people are saying that that's like $25k/3 months!

http://help.lms.linkedin.com/hc/en-us/articles/204141578-LinkedIn-AutoFill-Setup-Guide

http://www.marketing-mojo.com/blog/linkedin-lead-accelerator-is-it-worth-the-plunge/

Comment: Thanks for this - I EVENTUALLY got through to someone willing to help at LinkedIn by using their normal (non developer/ stack exchange) service about 10 times! They put me through to a developer and they told me this! Thanks for the help though!